# how to solve TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I transfer

```
A = [0.12075357905088335, -0.192198145631724, 0.9455373400335009, -0.6811922263715244, 0.7683786941009969, 0.033112227984689206, -0.3812622359989405]
```

to

```
A = [[0.12075357905088335], [-0.192198145631724], [0.9455373400335009], [-0.6811922263715244], [0.7683786941009969], [0.033112227984689206], [-0.3812622359989405]]
```

I tried to the code below but an error occurred:

```
new = []
for i in A:
    new.append.list(i)
```

> `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please could you paste the actual code you used in your question? The code you paste gives `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'list'`, it does not give a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Try [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), it is much more convenient:

```
new = [[i] for i in A]
```

---

#### Explanation

You are getting `TypeError` because you cannot apply `list()` function to value of type `float`. [This function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-list) takes an iterable as a parameter and `float` is not an iterable.

Another mistake is that you are using `new.append._something` instead of `new.append(_something)`: `append` is a [method](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html) of a `list` object, so you should provide an item to add as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You have a mistake, try:

```
new = []
for i in A:
    new.append([i])
```

Here is more beautiful solution:

```
new = [[i] for i in A]
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.append` is a method which requires an argument, e.g. `new.append(i)` or, in this case `new.append([i])`.

A list comprehension is a better idea, see [@IvanVinogradov's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49998511/9209546).

If you are happy using a 3rd party library, consider `numpy` for a vectorised solution:

```
import numpy as np

A = [0.12075357905088335, -0.192198145631724, 0.9455373400335009, -0.6811922263715244, 0.7683786941009969, 0.033112227984689206, -0.3812622359989405] 

A = np.array(A)[:, None]

print(A)

# [[ 0.12075358]
#  [-0.19219815]
#  [ 0.94553734]
#  [-0.68119223]
#  [ 0.76837869]
#  [ 0.03311223]
#  [-0.38126224]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using like that:

```
my_data=b['dataset']['data'][0][1]
useful_data=[i[1] for i in my_data]
```

So when you compile it gives you an error:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Try only:

```
my_data=b['dataset']['data']
```

Then you will get your data.