# Getting error 'float' object is not iterable when trying to check if values in the list of a list are less than zero

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list

```
d = [[-3.0, -3.0, -5.0, -4.0, -2.0], [-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 4.0], [-5.0, -4.0, -6.0, -6.0, -2.0], [-1.5, -2.5, -2.5, -1.5, -3.5]]
```

My goal is to create another list called Final such that, if all the values in particular list in list d are less than zero, then insert True in Final else append False

Example

```
each element in list d[0] is less than zero then insert True in Final
each element in list d[1] is not less than zero then insert False in Final

Therefore the desired output of Final = [True, False, True, True]
```

I wrote the following code for this purpose :

```
d = [[-3.0, -3.0, -5.0, -4.0, -2.0], [-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 4.0], [-5.0, -4.0, -6.0, -6.0, -2.0], [-1.5, -2.5, -2.5, -1.5, -3.5]]

Final = []

for i in range(len(d)):
    for j in range(len(d[0])):
        if all((p>0) for p in d[i][j]):
            final.append(True)
        else:
            final.append(False)
```

However, when I run the code, I get the error 'float' object is not iterable

I tried looking this error up on stackover flow ([how to solve TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998463/how-to-solve-typeerror-float-object-is-not-iterable/49998511))

However, since I'm trying to check list inside of lists, I'm not sure how to go about it. Appreciate any insights.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: d[i][j] is a float - as the error says, you can't iterate over it like `for i in d`

Answer (score 2):

Use `all()` in a list comprehension

**Example:**

```
d = [[-3.0, -3.0, -5.0, -4.0, -2.0], [-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 4.0], [-5.0, -4.0, -6.0, -6.0, -2.0], [-1.5, -2.5, -2.5, -1.5, -3.5]]

Final = [all(j < 0 for j in i) for i in d]
print(Final)
```

**Output:**

```
[True, False, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your inner `for loop` and change `all() function` if condition.
`for i in d` loop is iterating the `list of list`, where `i` is nested list. now compare nested list `i` with `all()` function condition.

- [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)- Return True if all elements of the iterable are true.

**Ex.**

```
d = [[-3.0, -3.0, -5.0, -4.0, -2.0], [-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 4.0], [-5.0, -4.0, -6.0, -6.0, -2.0], [-1.5, -2.5, -2.5, -1.5, -3.5]]
final = []

for i in d:
    if all(p<0 for p in i):
        final.append(True)
    else:
        final.append(False)

print(final)
```

**O/P:**

```
[True, False, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `any` in case you didn't know this :

```
final = [not any(j > 0 for j in i) for i in d] # this will also do the Job
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner solution

`Final = list(map(lambda x: all([y<0 for y in x]), d))`