# Why is 'float' object is not iterable?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, typeerror

I have difficulties to understand why I get the error     `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable` running the following code:

```
traces = [[ -122.29175806045532, 37.809512710254495 ],
           [ -122.29154348373412, 37.810233196634634 ],
           [ -122.29129672050475, 37.810996056903875 ],
           [ -122.29098558425902, 37.811801289748544 ],
           [ -122.29082465171813, 37.81219966485621 ],
           [ -122.2902774810791, 37.812106428321556 ],
           [ -122.28985905647279, 37.81201319166914 ] ]

for trace in traces:
    s = ";".join(map(lambda y: ",".join(str(x) for x in y), trace))
```

Comment: Maybe write out your oneliner as traditional `for` loops and you will see.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998463/how-to-solve-typeerror-float-object-is-not-iterable Similar issue ?

Comment: `trace` is something like `[1.2, 1.3]`, so `y` is something like 1.2. You're iterating over `y` `(str(x) for x in y)`, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is ok, but you don't need the outer for loop. So, just remove line
`for trace in traces:`
and fix `trace` to `traces` here

`s = ";".join(map(lambda y: ",".join(str(x) for x in y), trace))`

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple. How would you iterate over a single number? You can iterate over a list of floats but not over a single float number. You went too deep when looping 3 times. You are looping inside a mapping lambda function that comes from a loop (it's like doing 3 loops, while you need 2).

Take one loop out and it will work